# Obtaining iccid using CTCellularPlanProvisioningRequest

Tags: ios, swift, core-telephony

I'm trying to obtain the `iccid` from my device's SIM using `CoreTelephony`'s `CTCellularProvisionongRequest` using the code below:

```
    let ctCellularPlanProvisingRequest = CTCellularPlanProvisioningRequest()

func geticcid() -> String {
    if let iccid = ctCellularPlanProvisingRequest.iccid {
        print("iccid is: \(iccid)")
        return iccid
    }
    print("iccid is nil")
    return "nil"
}
```

I'm getting nil. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The class isn't documented yet, but I suspect that you will need a specific entitlement for your app to use the eSIM provisioning functions. Apple certainly wouldn't let just any app access the iccid

Comment: @shawn.t have you found any solution? it is iOS 12+ method.